# SSRS Check printing using MICR font

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, fonts, ssrs-2012

I need to create AP check for the invoices. I am using the MICR font at the bottom of a check in the SSRS report. I used the text box size as big as 3 times the font size. When I preview the report, the text shows just like Arial font. When I export to PDF and open the document properties of that PDF file, it shows that MICR font exists. But it is not showing like that MICR font that used in check routing/accounting number.

It does not work for in report viewer, exported PDF or word files.
Could anyone please guide me how to show that font in the text box?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it a TrueType font? Microsoft has openly stated that if you're using anything other than TrueType e.g. OpenType that you're likely to run into issues with SSRS and the Report Builder. OpenType is not unsupported but has limited support at best.

If a TrueType font is available for MICR, ensure it is installed on your client and server machines. When you install the font on your server, you will need to restart the Reporting Services service, or preferably the server, to detect changes. I found this article exceedingly helpful when setting up custom fonts for SSRS: [Setting up Custom Fonts with SQL Server Reporting Services](https://blogs.claritycon.com/blog/2010/01/utilizing-custom-fonts-with-sql-reporting-services-ssrs-and-exporting-to-pdf/).

The reason why you're seeing a font similar to Arial in your report is because of a limitation with Windows Forms Applications.

> The root cause is that Windows Forms applications support TrueType fonts and have limited support for OpenType fonts. If we attempt to use a font that is not supported in Report Builder or SQL Server Data Tool (SSDT) to design a report, the Microsoft Sans Serif font will be substituted.

Found at this [source](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/b987e1c8-1342-421c-b0a2-ed2245c619b8/opentype-fonts-supported-in-ssrs-2012?forum=sqlreportingservices).

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution. When Administrator installed the true type font with multi user license, still that font was not showing up for me. Only  Admin login account able to see that. But when I ran the same exe file under my user name, the font installed and I can able to see that. When I ran SSRS report and export into PDF, the font displays like MICR font. Like you said, restarting the server would solve the issue. We may need to restart the server before this report goes to production.